# Android - AlarmManager recovery

Tags: android, recovery, alarmmanager

Thanks to `TasKiller` I have reliable way to shutdown updates coming to my `AppWidget` from the `AlarmManager`!

Now, sarcasm aside, how do I recover from such event? So far I only see that the `Alerts` are resurrected only after rebooting the phone.

I can stick recovery code into few places such as various `Activity#onCreate` that belong to my app and my widget but is there a better way?

Also what if the alerts are OK - is there a way to detect that and not run `AlarmManager#setRepeating`?

Or is there a harm to run it multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, sarcasm aside, how do I recover
>   from such event?

I have heard that single-malt Scotch helps.

> So far I only see that the Alerts are
>   resurrected only after rebooting the
>   phone.

That is only if you are hooking the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast `Intent` and re-establishing the alarms.

Task killers are remarkably thorough, but they cannot stop a `BroadcastReceiver` from receiving system broadcasts, like `BOOT_COMPLETED`. You are welcome to find some other broadcast that you would like to receive to help regain control and re-establish your alarms.

> Also what if the alerts are OK - is
>   there a way to detect that and not run
>   AlarmManager#setRepeating? Or is there
>   a harm to run it multiple times?

You can `cancel()` an existing alarm. So, if you are concerned about possible duplicates, `cancel()` the current alarm (which hopefully fails quietly if the alarm does not exist), then set the alarm.

Comment: Well you don't even have to `cancel` - when you call schedule on the same pending intent your schedule is automatically reset. Thanks for your help Mark, much appreciated